# "Pay rise" vs "pay raise"

Tags: grammar, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

Which sentence below is correct?

> Ben received a pay rise.
>   Ben received a pay raise.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That depends.

> In American English, a person receives a raise  in salary. In British English it is a rise.

Source: [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/raise)

In each region you can even use *raise* / *rise* without *pay* and there is no question about what's increased:

> Ben received a raise.

or:

> Ben received a rise.

Comment: Sorry, but as a speaker of American English using the word "rise"instead of "raise" just sounds so .. wrong.  Even in the last case. Perhaps it's related to the informal idiom "get a rise out of" meaning to make someone upset.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm -  just based the general usage of the words in other contexts, I would say "pay rise" denotes some across the board increase that everyone got due to contract negotiations or gov't action.  A "pay raise" would denote that Bill alone got the increase.

Even so - it's a stretch and I would normally ask for clarification as the meaning is unclear - I'm not sure anyone else would see the difference.  It strikes me as the sort of differentiation that a specialist in accounting or management would make aot the normal guy on the street.

Answer (score -1):

The second is correct.  See [here](http://hubpages.com/hub/Grammar_Mishaps__Raise_vs_Rise) for a nice explanation of the difference.

Comment: the linked article is unclear on this point.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.